# fwrite and printing into an output file program

Tags: c, pointers, fwrite

if i am writing into file with fwrite as follows

```
char buffer[3]={255,255,255,'\0'};
char buffer2[3]={0,0,0,'\0'};

fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), outputFile);
fwrite(buffer2, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer2), outputFile);
```

what i am trying to understand is the third argument, sizeof(buffer)

my issue is that if the array has an appended '\0' nul character, does fwrite copy the nul character also into the file

also if i used a while loop to write into a file such as

```
 int i=0;

    while(i++<100){

     fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), outputFile);
     fwrite(buffer2, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer2), outputFile);

    }
```

what are the potential problems here directly to do with the nul character

also one more question , as i am having a problem with my program

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

   // check that the types have the size i'm relying on here
   assert (sizeof(bits8)  == 1);
   assert (sizeof(bits16) == 2);
   assert (sizeof(bits32) == 4);

   FILE *outputFile;
   int squareSize;

   outputFile = fopen(BMP_FILE, "wb");
   assert ((outputFile!=NULL) && "Cannot open file");

   writeHeader(outputFile);

   printf ("Enter square size (must be a factor of %d): \n", SIZE);
   scanf ("%d", &squareSize);
   assert (SIZE % squareSize == 0);


   char buffer[squareSize*BYTES_PER_PIXEL]; //white
   char buffer2[squareSize*BYTES_PER_PIXEL]; //black

   initialize(buffer, buffer2, squareSize);

   int line=0;
   int m=1;

      while(line<SIZE){

         if(line%squareSize==0&&m==1)
            m=0;
         else if(line%squareSize==1&&m==0)
            m=1;

         writeToFile(buffer,buffer2,m,outputFile,squareSize);

         line+=squareSize;

         printf("\nline is %d inside while loop ",line);

      }

   fclose(outputFile);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void writeHeader (FILE *file) {
   assert(sizeof (bits8) == 1);
   assert(sizeof (bits16) == 2);
   assert(sizeof (bits32) == 4);

   bits16 magicNumber = MAGIC_NUMBER;
   fwrite (&magicNumber, sizeof magicNumber, 1, file);

   bits32 fileSize = OFFSET + (SIZE * SIZE * BYTES_PER_PIXEL);
   fwrite (&fileSize, sizeof fileSize, 1, file);

   bits32 reserved = 0;
   fwrite (&reserved, sizeof reserved, 1, file);

   bits32 offset = OFFSET;
   fwrite (&offset, sizeof offset, 1, file);

   bits32 dibHeaderSize = DIB_HEADER_SIZE;
   fwrite (&dibHeaderSize, sizeof dibHeaderSize, 1, file);

   bits32 width = SIZE;
   fwrite (&width, sizeof width, 1, file);

   bits32 height = SIZE;
   fwrite (&height, sizeof height, 1, file);

   bits16 planes = NUMBER_PLANES;
   fwrite (&planes, sizeof planes, 1, file);

   bits16 bitsPerPixel = BITS_PER_PIXEL;
   fwrite (&bitsPerPixel, sizeof bitsPerPixel, 1, file);

   bits32 compression = NO_COMPRESSION;
   fwrite (&compression, sizeof compression, 1, file);

   bits32 imageSize = (SIZE * SIZE * BYTES_PER_PIXEL);
   fwrite (&imageSize, sizeof imageSize, 1, file);

   bits32 hResolution = PIX_PER_METRE;
   fwrite (&hResolution, sizeof hResolution, 1, file);

   bits32 vResolution = PIX_PER_METRE;
   fwrite (&vResolution, sizeof vResolution, 1, file);

   bits32 numColors = NUM_COLORS;
   fwrite (&numColors, sizeof numColors, 1, file);

   bits32 importantColors = NUM_COLORS;
   fwrite (&importantColors, sizeof importantColors, 1, file);

}
void initialize(char *buffer, char*buffer2, int size){

   //white for buffer 255,255,255 1 pixel
   //black for buffer2 00,00,00 1 pixel

   int buf = 255;
   int buf2 = 0;
   int i = 0;

   while(i<size*3){
      buffer[i]=buf;
      buffer2[i]=buf2;

      printf("\nbuffer 1 [i] is %c and i is %d\n",buffer[i],i);
      printf("buffer 2 [i] is %c and i is %d\n",buffer2[i],i);

      i++;

     // printf("\nline ran %d times inside initialize loop ",i);
   }


   buffer[i]='\0';
   buffer2[i]='\0';

   printf("%s\n",buffer);
   printf("%s",buffer2);

}
void writeToFile(char *buffer,char *buffer2, int m, FILE *file,
int squareSize){

int k = 0;



           // printf("\nline ran %d times",line);

               if(m==0){
                  while(k<(SIZE/squareSize)){
                     fwrite(buffer2, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer2), file);
                     k+=1;
                     fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), file);
                     k+=1;

                   //  printf("\nline ran %d times inside first if ",line);

                    }                  
                } 
               else if(m==1){
                  while(k<(SIZE/squareSize)){
                     fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), file);
                     k+=1;
                     fwrite(buffer2, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer2), file);
                     k+=1;

                   //  printf("\nline ran %d times inside second else if",line);

                    }

                }



}
```

the program is supposed to write to a file that is supposed to be a bmp file

the header write output function works fine

however i am having problem with the function initialize and the function writeToFile which i think has to do witht he nul pointer because i think fwrite is taking the nul pointer over as well and causing the bmp file to have the wrong information throw into it , also if i do remove teh nul character does fwrite produce problems by not stopping at the specified spot or does it stil copy correctly

i dont know what the problem is but the program is not writing in the order that i imagined 
i have been at it ALL NIGHT and it still does not function correctly i am not sure where the problem is

the program is supposed to write into a 512 by 512 output file which is supposed to print out checkered black and white squares based on the input by user of a square which is a factor of 512

so that if the person chooses the input to be 256 , the program is supposed to divide the 512 by 512 space into 4 square with the first square being black then white, then white then black and etc

if the person choose 16 as the size of square in pixels, then i am supposed to divide the space into squares of 16 pixels sides ion the order of starting with black then white(across) next line above white then black all the way to the end

i think the problem is with my write to File function but i am not sure what the problem is, really confusing

hope you can help to give me some suggestions on how to deal with this problem

any help would be highly appreciated so that i can get this over and done with

Comment: the way that i have set the program to work is that what i did was passs the squaresize to the function writeToFile

then the while loop inside that function is supposed to write 

square size(so that if the side of square is 16 it would initialize 16 *3 times into the array of combinations of 255 255 255 for white 
and 0 0 0 for black 

so then i can just output to the file the white and black sides in one go, instead of going through each pixel one at a time 

and based which line it is on i have set a flag as to which colour it starts to print with

Comment: `char buffer[3]={255,255,255,'\0'};` is an error. You specified size 3, but gave 4 initializers.

Comment: first clearly learn about arrays and pointers. then try file IO. Atleast you dont know how to delcare a array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `fwrite()` is the size of each object, and the third argument is the number of objects. In your case, you tell it to write 4 objects of size `1`, but here you could just write one object of size `4` just as easily.

"Nul characters" are irrelevant here, since they terminate strings, and `fwrite()` explicitly deals with binary objects, not strings. It'll write exactly what you give it to the file.

As an aside, a regular unqualified `char` can be (and often is) signed, rather than unsigned, so trying to stuff all those `255`s into them may not be wise. `unsigned char` may be better for this.

In the `writeToFile()` function in your third block of code, this:

```
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), file);
```

is a simple misunderstanding of how the `sizeof` operator works. In this context, `buffer` is not an array, it's a pointer to `char` that you have passed to the function. `sizeof` will therefore give you the size of a character pointer, usually 4 or 8 bytes, and that size will obviously be totally unrelated to the size of the buffer it points to. If `char` pointers are 8 bytes on your system, then `sizeof(buffer)` in this context will always evaluate to `8`, regardless of whether you initially set up a 3 byte array, or a 4 byte array, or a 672 byte array.

To make what you want to do work in a function like this, you'll have to explicitly pass to the `writeToFile()` function the size of the buffer you created, and use that instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: so i should change fwrite to 

fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, outputFile);
fwrite(buffer2, sizeof(char), 1, outputFile);

and also in my code 

char unsigned buffer[squareSize*BYTES_PER_PIXEL]; //white
char unsigned buffer2[squareSize*BYTES_PER_PIXEL]; //black

instead of what i have now

char buffer[squareSize*BYTES_PER_PIXEL]; //white
char buffer2[squareSize*BYTES_PER_PIXEL]; //black

so that it is not limited to -127 to 126?

thanks for noticing by the way i was completely oblivious to such an important detail!!

Comment: It's hard to tell, since lots of code in comments is practically unreadable, but `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, outputFile);` will write precisely one byte, which is probably not what you want. `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, and it's generally considered bad form to use it for that reason, it's better to just write `1` instead.

Comment: okay so it should be

`fwrite(buffer2, 1, sizeof(buffer2), outputFile);`
`fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), outputFile);`

Comment: Yes, if you want to write the entire buffer. You'll first want to fix the problem Matt McNabb pointed out, where you twice declare an array of three elements, but then try to stuff four items into it. Your compiler should be complaining to you about this.

Comment: yea that was actually not part of my code i was using that as an example to understand hw fwrite works , hence why my compiler has not been givng me issues about it

Comment: just to recoup if the code remained as 

`fwrite(buffer2, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer2),outputFile)` this would cause problems with fwrite?

Comment: @yukapuka: Provided that `buffer2` has been declared within the current scope as an array and not, for instance, declared as a pointer or passed into a function as a pointer, it should be fine as far as `fwrite()` is concerned. `sizeof(char)` is not actually wrong, its just 11 characters longer than it needs to be. If your `writeToFile()` function is what you're doing, then this will never work, since `sizeof(buffer)` here will give you the size of a `char` pointer, usually 4 or 8 bytes, and will tell you nothing about the size of the actual buffer it points to.

Comment: See updated answer. This is a prime example of why it's important to include your real code in questions (include it in respect of the question you're asking, not as a separate unrelated block further down), and not code you're using "as an example" which may not - and, in this case, actually did not - demonstrate the problem you were actually having.

Comment: i see the problem here i do in fact pass the buffer and buffer2 to a function to do the writing into the file

Comment: one more question i wanted to clarify for myself if you dont mind helping me 

when we use fwrite(...) what determines that what it writes to will be for example written in hexadecimal as in my case  

if i am writing to a file which i call file.bmp, what determines that it will be converted to hexadecimal 

if fwrite does in fact copy the contents of an array which is say {255,255,255} to a file, what determines that it will be converted to FF FF FF , is it the header file of the BMP file or something else that deals with the conversion? 

or does the compiler do it automatically?

Comment: There is no "conversion", with `fwrite()` you're writing binary data, not text. `255` and `0xFF` are just two ways of representing the same value in your program. Your actual physical file will be stored in some way that can be accurately represented as binary bits, that's ultimately what's going to be stored. `255` and `0xFF` are just two alternative ways of representing `0b11111111`, there's nothing that is or needs to be "converted" once your program has been compiled. It matters in text files whether you're writing `'F'` or `'2'`, but for binary files it's all just represented as numbers.

Comment: That is, it "matters in text files" when you need to interpret which characters the binary bits of the file are intended to represent. All files, text or otherwise, are ultimately just streams of bits that some program ultimately has to interpret in one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** does fwrite copy the nul character also into the file?

**Answer:** The way you are calling it, the answer is "Yes". The third argument to the buffer is the number of objects that you wish to write to the stream.

*Solution to your problem*

You can change your variables

```
char buffer[3]={255,255,255,'\0'}; // This should be a compiler error/warning.
char buffer2[3]={0,0,0,'\0'};      // You have 4 items in {} for an array of size 3.
```

to

```
char buffer[3]={255,255,255};
char buffer2[3]={0,0,0};
```

You need a `'\0'` at the end of an array of `char` only if you want to treat the array as a null-terminated string. Since you are using the array to store only pixel values, you don't need to have the terminating null character in your array.

Potential pitfalls of not having the null character is that most functions that work with strings expect a terminating null character. They won't work with `buffer` or `buffer2`. Don't use:

1. Any of the standard string manipulation functions, such as `strlen`, `strcpy`.
2. `printf("%s", buffer);`.
3. and many other functions.

Considering your usage of those variable, I don't think you need to use them.

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite` and `fread` don't care at all about zero bytes. They simply write or read the number of bytes you ask for.

And note that `buffer2` does not just have a `'\0'` appended but is in fact all `'\0'`s since `0` and `'\0'` are identical in that context.

You don't need to zero-terminate your buffers since they aren't strings, they're just data and can contain zero-bytes within them.